# What is the difference between "quasar dev" and "quasar dev #"

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Completely new to Quasar and following a video tutorial.  The tutorial tells me to use "quasar dev" but that doesn't work.  The info in the text from the "quasar create" tells me to use "quasar dev #" (which does work).  What is the difference? What does the # mean?

Comment: Looks like you've come across an undocumented command feature. Docs [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/commands-list#create). Normally, `#` denotes the start of a comment in CLI. Adding one at the end of a CLI command doesn't make much sense and it shouldn't affect the execution of the command. You might want to try asking it on their repo. When/if you get an answer, remember to post it here, for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it does it, but I have found how to switch it off.

In the quasar.config.js file, remove the following lines of code from the `build:` section:

```
  target: {
    browser: [ 'es2019', 'edge88', 'firefox78', 'chrome87', 'safari13.1' ],
    node: 'node16'
  },
```

This code is put there by the create process and I suspect it being there provides some functionality which I am not currently using as a complete beginner.